# Serve SPA multi-tenants through AWS CloudFront from a single S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, multi-tenant

Given the following considerations:

- Single S3 bucket containing static Frontend SPA files.
- Frontend is being served through CloudFront, where each tenant has their own CloudFront distribution (tenantA.domain.com, ... tenantZ.domain.com).
- Each tenant has their own configurations (which can be fetched from a Configuration service resolving the domain).
- Each CloudFront needs to inject such configurations in the Frontend at run time.

[image: Consider the diagram below.]

---

I am thinking of a Lambda function, that queries the "Configuration service" (possibly caching the response), and then setting globally scoped variables (e.g. `window.config1`) for the SPA to use. Is such a scenario possible through CloudFront? Is there a more common/standardized way?

Comment: is there a problem if the frontend fetches the configuration from an api call or a S3 bucket get call without needing cloudfront to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do this, I have done it! (Been meaning to write a blog about it.
I work on a multi-tenant SAAS platform, where tenants have their own identity provider configuration for Cognito. What I did was I had a file `config.js`, looks something like this which had a bunch of Cognito settings: (I'm using ReactJS)

```
window.TENANT_CONFIG = {
      REACT_APP_USERPOOL_REDIRECT_SIGNIN : "https://todo.somesite.com/",
      REACT_APP_USERPOOL_REDIRECT_SIGNOUT : "https://todo.somesite.com/",
      REACT_APP_WEB_CLIENT_ID : "todo",
      REACT_APP_TENANT_NAME : "todo" ....
    };
```

This tile is included as a javascript script at the top of my `index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/config.js"></script>
```

**Lambda**

You need a Lambda function in `us-east-1` which will become a Lambda at Edge in your Cloudfront distribution. This function must be only `128 MB` and have no environment variables. You can refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) documentation on how to create the Lambda function. But in general you need to construct the `window.TEN...`. You can read the `event.Records[0].cf.request.headers['host'][0].value` to determine wether your call came from one domain or the other, and construct the appropriate `config.js` file. My Lambda function actually reads configuration from an S3 bucket. Yours will be different.

**CloudFront**

If you can generate the correct certificate, you only need one `CloudFront` domain actually. Just make sure you have added the CNames of all the different subdomains. Then you need to add a behaviour with a path pattern of: `config.js`. Configure a `Lambda Function Associations` of `Viewer Request` and Specify your `Lambda Function ARN`. And you are good to go!

Comment: That exactly describes the solution I am implementing! (passing Cognito user pools configuration per tenant). I'd love to take a look your blog post about it once its written.

Comment: Haha, I really am meaning to do it! Got bought my domain and everything. Yeah in Cognito I have different web app clients for each tenant, I lookup the config based on the subdomain they visit. Each tenant might have a different IDP provider. Also when users authenticate I add their tenantId to their id-token. Each tenant also is a group in Cognito to enable searching for users within a tenant. Yeah that's some of the stuff I've been doing, it works really well, hard to find all the info to tie it together.

Comment: @Derrops Did you end up writing a blog about it? I very much am looking on guidance for achieving the same thing and haven't found any useful resources so far

Comment: There is actually a video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwQ5lipGTBI on pretty much what I did but a bit different. I've actually decided to turn this into a product customers can deploy to do some of the heavy lifting of developing a SaaS application, because it is really a lot of work and doing this yourself is very difficult.