# What are the challenges with a user pool per tenant in a an AWS multi-tenant serverless application

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, multi-tenant, saas

I am considering creating a user pool per tenant based on the recommended multi-tenant architecture (for ex: https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/saas/identity-with-cognito/)

The rest of the resources in the application are going to be using pooled resources (for ex: API gateway, dynamoDB tables). Considering the silo model just for the Cognito/auth part of the application.

Application requirements:

1. Subdomain per tenant i.e. tenant1.company.com an tenant2.company.com
2. A user can belong to multiple tenants(Forex: User A can be in `tenant1` and `tenant2`)
3. Need to be able to list all users for a particular tenant
4. Data residency restrictions for personally identifiable information

I believe If I was to use the same Cognito user pool for all tenants, I could force users to use a different email for a new tenant i.e `abc@tenant1.com` for `Tenant1` and  `abc+tenant2@tenant2.com` for `Tenant2`.

But to list all users for a particular tenant, I imagine the same user pool for all tenants will not work as tenant_id will be a custom attribute.

I could also ensure data residency restrictions by creating a user pool per tenant. However, how do I handle regional failover in this case?

Also, Is subdomain per tenant supported with this approach?

I hear that the user pool per tenant is constant pain and should be avoided. What are some of the pain points?

For my use case, Does it look like that I should opt for an AuthZ provider instead like auth0 or authress?

Comment: Why has it been voted to close?

Comment: Your question is unfocused and too broad. My advice, you would tell us the use case without mentioning any services because it's hard to define the problem against the solution specifically with AWS.